# Selenium Webscraping - Print element that is not visible on the site but its on Inspect

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s2jW.png)

I'm trying to print this 91040 from the site but I can't seem to do it and I think the reason is that 91040 is not visible on the site but only on inspect.

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="code-container"]//span[2]')
```

When I paste this XPATH in the find bar on Inspect it locates the item but when I'm trying to print the element nothing gets printed. I tried these options.

```
print(element)
print(element.text)
```

So I'm thinking that the problem is that 91040 is not an actual visible text.

Comment: What is the output of this `print(element.text)` ?

Comment: it prints nothing. empty line

Comment: You'd probably want to check the visibility of the element when using webdriver waits.

Comment: The element is never visible. Its just something hidden in the inspect.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem I found the answer

```
hidden_text = element.get_attribute("textContent")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).